# Solution to Codejam 2019 1A (Pylons) in C

Tags: c, c99

The following is my solution to the Pylons problem from Codejam 2019: https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051635/0000000000104e03.

> Our Battlestarcraft Algorithmica ship is being chased through space by persistent robots called Pylons! We have just teleported to a new galaxy to try to shake them off of our tail, and we want to stay here for as long as possible so we can buy time to plan our next move... but we do not want to get caught!
>
> This galaxy is a flat grid of R rows and C columns; the rows are numbered from 1 to R from top to bottom, and the columns are numbered from 1 to C from left to right. We can choose which cell to start in, and we must continue to jump between cells until we have visited each cell in the galaxy exactly once. That is, we can never revisit a cell, including our starting cell.
>
> We do not want to make it too easy for the Pylons to guess where we will go next. Each time we jump from our current cell, we must choose a destination cell that does not share a row, column, or diagonal with that current cell. Let (i, j) denote the cell in the i-th row and j-th column; then a jump from a current cell (r, c) to a destination cell (r', c') is invalid if and only if any of these is true:
>
> r = r'
> c = c'
> r - c = r' - c'
> r + c = r' + c'
>
> Can you help us find an order in which to visit each of the R × C cells, such that the move between any pair of consecutive cells in the sequence is valid? Or is it impossible for us to escape from the Pylons? In summary, the task is to visit every cell in an RxC grid exactly once, without jumping to a cell that shares a row, column, or diagonal with the previous cell. If it is possible to visit every cell, the solution should print the sequence of steps.
>
> This is a standard backtracking problem, but there is a caveat. We want to check cells in "random" order, or otherwise the solution will be too slow.

The code is correct, i.e. it gets two green checkmarks. I'd appreciate any feedback!

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_R 20
#define MAX_C 20

bool backtrack(bool visited_cells[][MAX_C], int sequence[][2], int R, int C, int visited_count, int r, int c) {
  // Total number of cells
  int N = R * C;
  // Return true if we have visited every cell.
  if (visited_count == N) {
    return true;
  }
  // Otherwise, try every legal jump in "random" order.
  visited_count++;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    // Next row and column to visit
    // Note that checking cells in consecutive order will be very slow.
    int nrc = i * 29 % N;
    // Next row
    int nr = nrc / C;
    // Next column
    int nc = nrc % C;
    // Skip the cell if we have already visited it.
    if (visited_cells[nr][nc]) {
      continue;
    }
    // Skip any invalid jumps.
    if (visited_count > 1 && (r == nr || c == nc || r - c == nr - nc || r + c == nr + nc)) {
      continue;
    }
    // Record our chosen cell.
    visited_cells[nr][nc] = true;
    sequence[visited_count-1][0] = nr;
    sequence[visited_count-1][1] = nc;
    // Recurse and try to visit the rest of the cells.
    if (backtrack(visited_cells, sequence, R, C, visited_count, nr, nc)) {
      // We have found a solution.
      return true;
    }
    // If we failed, undo our choice and try another cell.
    visited_cells[nr][nc] = false;
  }
  // We haven't found a solution.
  return false;
}

bool solve(int sequence[][2], int R, int C) {
  // Array to keep track of visited cells.
  bool visited_cells[MAX_R][MAX_C];
  // Initially, we haven't visited any cells.
  for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < C; c++) {
      visited_cells[r][c] = false;
    }
  }
  // Try to visit every cell using exhaustive search.
  return backtrack(visited_cells, sequence, R, C, 0, -1, -1);
}

int main(void) {
  // Number of test cases
  int T = 0;
  scanf("%d", &T);
  // Solve each test case.
  for (int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
    // Number of rows
    int R = 0;
    // Number of columns
    int C = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &R, &C);
    // Array to keep track of a solution
    int sequence[R * C][2];
    // Solve the case.
    bool possible = solve(sequence, R, C);
    // Print our verdict.
    printf("Case #%d: %s\n", t, possible ? "POSSIBLE" : "IMPOSSIBLE");
    if (possible) {
      // Print our solution sequence.
      for (int i = 0; i < R * C; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", sequence[i][0] + 1, sequence[i][1] + 1);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example output:

```
$ cat tests.txt
2
2 2
2 5
$ ./solution < tests.txt
Case #1: IMPOSSIBLE
Case #2: POSSIBLE
1 1
2 4
1 2
2 5
1 3
2 1
1 4
2 2
1 5
2 3
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These coding competition sites are great at teaching you tricks and algorithms, but they are terrible at teaching you to write readable and maintainable code. Let's see how we can improve the latter.

## Naming things

Short variable names save some typing, but it is hard to read code that only contains abbreviations. Only use one-letter variable names if that letter is used in a very common way, like `i` as a loop iterator, or if its scope is very limited, so that you don't have to go searching through the code to find out where it is declared and what it means. Here are some suggestions for replacements:

- `R` → `n_rows`. Now we no longer have to guess that r stands for row. The prefix `n_` is commonly used to indicate "number of". You might also drop the prefix and just write `rows`, but see below about that.
- `C` -> `n_cols` or `n_columns`
- `r` -> `row`
- `c` -> `col` or `column`
- `N` -> `n_cells`. If you drop the prefix, it will be `cells`, but notice how you already have the array `visible_cells`: now `cells` might start to sound like an array as well. This is where `n_` removes any doubt.
- `nr` -> `next_row`
- `nc` -> `next_col` or `next_column`
- `nrc` -> `next_cell`

Names like `backtrack` and `solve` are very generic. Backtrack what? Solve what and how? If you use them in a larger program where you need to solve different kinds of things, having these generic names in the global namespace will cause a problem when linking your code. So either give them more unique names, or make sure these names are not visible outside of the source file they are in, by making these functions [`static`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration).

## Don't hesitate to create `struct`s

A great way to make your code easier to write, more maintainable and more self-documenting is by creating `struct`s for things that always occur together. For example, you have a 2-dimensional array of integers named `sequence`, but actually it's just a 1-dimensional array of coordinates. You can make it look like the latter if you create a `struct` that describes a coordinate:

```
typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
} coordinate;
```

And then you can write:

```
static bool backtrack(…, coordinate sequence[], …) {
    …
    sequence[visited_count - 1].row = next_row;
    sequence[visited_count - 1].col = next_col;
    …
}
```

But it gets better if you make more use of `coordinate`. Use it everywhere you have a combination of row and column. For example:

```
static bool backtrack(…, coordinate sequence[], coordinate size,
                      int visited_count, coordinate pos) {
    int n_cells = size.row * size.col;
    …
    coordinate next_pos = {next_cell / size.cols, next_cell % size.cols};
    …
    sequence[visited_count - 1] = next_pos;

    if (backtrack(…, sequence, size, visited_count, next_pos)) {
        …
    }
    …
}
```

Next, consider that your algorithm has some state that it has to pass to `backtrack` every time. This gets easier if you group all the state in a `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
    coordinate *sequence;
    coordinate size;
    bool visited_cells[MAX_ROWS][MAX_COLS];
} backtrack_state;
```

Note that this includes all the state that is *shared* by all invocations of `backtrack()`, it doesn't include the variables that are *local* to each invocation (`visited_count`, `r` and `c`). Now you can write:

```
static bool backtrack(backtrack_state *state, int visited_count,
                      coordinate pos) {
    int n_cells = state->size.row * state->size.col;
    …
    coordinate next_pos = {next_cell / size.cols, next_cell % size.cols};
    …
    state->sequence[visited_count - 1] = next_pos;

    if (backtrack(state, visited_count, next_pos)) {
        …
    }
    …
}

static bool solve(coordinate sequence[], coordinate size) {
    backtrack_state state = {sequence, size, {{0}}};
    return backtrack(&state, 0, (coordinate){-1, -1});
}
```

Note how we can initialize the state, including the two-dimensional array `visited_cells`, all in one go.

## Simplify functions

Try to keep functions simple and concise. If you find out you are doing a lot of things in one function, see if you can split it up in a meaningful way. For example, in `main()`, you read the number of test cases, and then proceed to process each test case in sequence. You can create a function that just does one test case, that way the code simplifies like so:

```
static void process_test_case(int case_nr) {
    coordinate size;
    scanf("%d %d", &size.row, &size.col);

    int n_cells = size.row * size.col;
    coordinate sequence[n_cells];
    bool possible = solve(sequence, size);

    printf("Case #%d: %s\n", case_nr, possible ? "POSSIBLE" : "IMPOSSIBLE");
    if (possible) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n_cells; i++) {
          printf("%d %d\n", sequence[i].row + 1, sequence[i].col + 1);
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int n_cases;
    scanf("%d", &n_cases);

    for (int case_nr = 1; case_nr <= n_cases; case_nr++) {
        process_test_case(case_nr);
    }
}
```

Note that this also automatically helps document the code: we now have a name for exactly that piece of code that processes a single test case, so you don't need a comment to explain that. That also brings me to:

## Avoid unnecessary comments

You have added a lot of comments to your code, but some of them are not really necessary. If it is obvious from the code what is going on, you don't need a comment that says exactly the same thing. Of course, if you use cryptic variable and function names, you might need comments to decode what is going on, but if you have clear variable and function names, the need for comments often goes away. Consider:

```
// Total number of cells
int N = R * C;
```

Yes, `N` is so generic, it often means "number of things", but what things? Now consider:

```
int n_cells = size.row * size.col;
```

The name `n_cells` implies it is the number of cells, so now you no longer have to explain that. It is now also clear that it's the product of the size in rows and columns, instead of resistance times capacitance, or whatever `R` and `C` might mean if you don't already know the context.

If you have a complex expression and need to explain what it means, consider assigning it to a variable with a clear name first. Maybe split up very long expressions into smaller ones first. You can also create helper functions. For example:

```
static bool is_valid_jump(coordinate from, coordinate to) {
    if (from.row == to.row) {
       return false;
    }

    if (from.col == to.col) {
       return false;
    }
    …
}
…
if (visited_count > 1 && !is_valid_jump(pos, next_pos)) {
    continue;
}
```

Some comments are very necessary though. Consider the calculation of the next position. You are hinting that scanning sequentially is going to be to slow. But what about that `% 29`? Here a comment explaining in more detail what is going on would be very helpful. It's not really choosing a random position, but perhaps this very pseudo-random way is good enough? How was the constant 29 chosen?

Comment: Great! I really appreciate you taking the time to review my code. Your feedback is excellent!